# uimodalpresentationpagesheet goes under the status bar

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uinavigationbar, uimodalpresentationstyle

In the FirstView by pressing a button, SecondView is presented in UIModalPresentationPageSheet

```
secondVC.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
```

The SecondView appears fine (its upper bound is next to the status bar) #1.
Then in the SecondView,by pressing a button, ThirdView is presented in this way:

```
    thirdVC.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFullScreen; 
    //I tried also commenting it, but the error occurs anyway.
```

In this ThirdView there is an UINavigationBar added in the xib and it is partially under the status bar (first problem) #2. When from the ThirdView user goes to the SecondView, it doesn't appear fine anymore: its upper bound this time is partially under the status bar #3.

How I can resolve it?

(it's an iPad app)
(also in the SecondView there is an UINavigationBar added in the xib)

Edit: Screenshots
!#1
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SETq5.png)

!#2
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydi2u.png)

!#3
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ihlC.png)

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: yes, you're right. I just added them.